# Hue in Plotly and cufflinks

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plotly, cufflinks

I need to create an interactive scatter plot and need to use hue option ( AS USED IN SEABORN ). I'm using Plotly and cufflinks to create scatter but I'm unable to get hue option in it. Can anyone pls help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species",
                 size='petal_length', hover_data=['petal_width'])
fig.show()
```

[Plotly Documentation](https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/)

See **Color in px.scatter similar to hue**.